# How can I delete the new files when I undo pending changes in TFS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In .Net Core or .net Standard project, when I add a new file to TFS source control. After I undo these pending changes, these new files will still exist there and be compiled. Is there a way when I undo pending changes, the file will be physically deleted on my local?

Comment: You can do this from the Solution Explorer window. Right click on the file and choose `Delete`. If you delete the file it will also remove it from the list of pending changes.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice, that's a way to do it, but every time need to delete these files manually is annoying.

Comment: I had to delete [+] file entry showing in Source Control Explorer before the "Pending Changes" for file in Team Explorer would go away.